# When there are different sized Text in a HStack, top alignment doesn’t apply to larger sized text

Tags: ios, text, swiftui, alignment, hstack

I have a HStack with multiple elements, particularly two `Text`s with different font sizes. I want both text to be aligned to the top of the view.

```
HStack(alignment: .top) {
    Image(systemName: "cloud.drizzle.fill")
    Text("14°")
        .font(.largeTitle)
    Text("86%")
        .font(.callout)
    Spacer()
}
```

However, the first (larger) `Text` is outputted below the other two:

[image]

Comment: It *is* aligned correctly. What you observe is just the nature of this font. You can add some background color behind each text to see for yourself.

Comment: Noted, thanks. Although I got a workaround, I must remind myself of this possibility if/when I come across this issue or similar in the future.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually it's aligned correctly , add backgrounds to each `Text` and you will find that the frame of the `Text` is aligned correctly

but to solve the case that you are looking for , I did a hack for you , by doing some calculs

The result:

[image]

## 1) Alignement of the two `Text`

- Put both of them in one `HStack` , with `alignment: .firstTextBaseline`
- Then play on the second text , by adding a `baselineOffset` with `(bigFont.capHeight - smallFont.capHeight)`

You can learn more about fonts , but the main information that you need is this :

[image]

So your code will be :

```
 HStack(alignment: .firstTextBaseline) {
                Text("14°")
                    .font(Font(bigFont))
                    .background(Color.blue)
                
                Text("86%")
                    .font(Font(smallFont))
                    .baselineOffset((bigFont.capHeight - smallFont.capHeight))
                    .background(Color.yellow)
                Spacer()
            }
```

## 2) Align the Image with the text :

- by adding a padding which will be equal to `bigFont.lineHeight-bigFont.ascender` (go back to the picture on top , to see how I calculated it )

And the final code :

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var pickerSelection = ""
    
    let bigFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 50)
    let smallFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment:.top) {
            Image(systemName: "cloud.drizzle.fill")
                .background(Color.red)
                .padding(.top, bigFont.lineHeight-bigFont.ascender)
            HStack(alignment: .firstTextBaseline) {
                Text("14°")
                    .font(Font(bigFont))
                    .background(Color.blue)
                
                Text("86%")
                    .font(Font(smallFont))
                    .baselineOffset((bigFont.capHeight - smallFont.capHeight))
                    .background(Color.yellow)
                Spacer()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

PS : I added backgrounds to show you the real frames of each view

Comment: Wow, just amazing! Works a charm and, most importantly, its flexibility will be super handy.

Answer (score 0):

Currently the texts are aligned by top. but the large text has ascent height that is larger than small text. so the align is not top of text.
Unfortunately, SwiftUI doesn't support the alignment of top of text.
But you can align the top of text manually like as following code.

```
HStack(alignment: .top) {
    Image(systemName: "cloud.drizzle.fill")
    Text("14°")
        .font(.largeTitle).padding(.top, -5.0)
    Text("86%")
        .font(.callout)
    Spacer()
}
```

Comment: Yep, I should have mentioned it at the top but I am aware that I could force what I’m after by setting the padding or offset but I don’t believe this to be a flexible solution when considering different font/display sizes. Thanks anyway!